# Fill rest of div after set pixel div

Tags: html, css

I have a varying width div. Inside are two others, one is fixed width, the other is supposed to fill the rest of the area.  But I can't get it to always fill.  Depending on the width of the outer-box, it is either too small, or is too big and drops below inner-box-1.  How do I get inner-box-2 to fill the rest of outer-box?

http://jsfiddle.net/Y57YP/

**HTML**

```
<div id ="outer-box">
   <div id="inner-box-1"></div>
   <div id="inner-box-2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer-box{
  width:50%;
  background:#fcc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inner-box-1{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:#ccc;
  float:left;
}
#inner-box-2{
  height:50px;
  width:80%;
  background:#555;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those odd answers that is easy but totally non-intuitive. You need to trigger [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context) by using the overflow property in conjunction with the float property.

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Y57YP/2/)**.

```
#inner-box-2{
   height:50px;
   background:#555;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

All I did was remove the width and float from your `#inner-box-2` div and add an `overflow:auto`